# How do I get an if input("xyz") value somewhere other than the if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if it were possible to get a value out of an if statement without adding more lines of code

ex:

```
if input('Seed Generation | N to generate a new seed\n') not in ['N','n','',' ']:
    random.seed(userInput) #I want what the user inputed to be here
```

If the user were to input "123" I would want the value of userInput to be 123. The only major reason I want to do this is to learn how to condense my code and make it easier to read.

Comment: Also "condense code" does not necessarily mean "easier to read". Sometimes even the opposite...

Comment: It did in deed, thank you very much :)

Comment: I know condensing code can sometimes make certain things harder to read. However, I found (before and after I had the wrong syntax) that it was easier with one line of code in this situation.